# Anti-spam question implemented into contact html form but still getting spam messages, how to stop?

Tags: html, contact-form, spam, spam-prevention, email-spam

We implemented the below anti-spam question our into html contact form. Also google recaptcha is active on the form. But still getting spam dating and automated other spam messages.

Here is the anti-spam question code:

```
<td align=center><font class="err"><TMPL_VAR msg></font><label for="turingtest"> <strong>Anti-Spam Question:</strong> Which is the wrong name of this website?: example, link or example.com? *</label>
<br>
<input type="text" required="required" pattern="[ ]*(link)[ ]*" title="Pick the fluffiest animal"/>
<br><input name="send" type="submit" name="btn" value="<TMPL_VAR lang_send_message>"></td>
```

And how to implement much more powerful anti-spam question into contact form?

Comment: This question might be a better fit on [Webmasters.SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but you should probably re-phrase it so that it is not a matter of opinion ("WHY?").

Comment: ok edited and will ask that too